# What is com.hmdglobal.app.customizationclient.OTAApplication?

Tags: nokia

I keep receiving an error about the app "com.hmdglobal.app.customizationclient.OTAApplication" crashing on my Nokia 2.2. What does this app do?

The app can't be uninstalled and can't be disabled, and has full access to call logs, phone and storage. Based on the name, I presume it's created by [Nokia](https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_us/privacyportal) to harvest my personal data.

Am I being paranoid or is this app malicious in any way?

Comment: Based on the package name I would assume that this is the app that searches in background for system updates for your phone (OTA = Over The Air updates).

Comment: I have had the same problem on my Nokia 4.2 for the last few days (since approximately 2021-03-04). Since our devices were both released in the spring of 2019, I wonder whether that sadly means they no longer qualify for Android updates? EDIT: Scrap that, there's a report on the XDA forum of the same thing on a Nokia 5.4. So probably just a bug.